cgroups user slice directory is not getting recognized under /sys/fs/cgroups on Centos 7. 3
I am using Centos7.3 and want to implement a cgroups to limit resources for all the login users.
I am using the concept of Dropin files by creating the directory /etc/systemd/system/user-.slice.d/ and creating the configuration file under that directory and doing the systemctl daemon-reload.
When the user login I don't see any directory is getting created under /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice with name user-{UID}.slice and the default settings is not getting applied. Same is working with Alma 8 / 9 .

systemd version - 219
cgroups version - 1



I am using the concept of Dropin files by creating the directory /etc/systemd/system/user-.slice.d/

The ability to place drop-ins in "prefix" directories was only implemented in systemd v239 (which came out ~3 years after the release of v219). Before that, only "exact match" drop-in directories were considered.

systemd/NEWS
CHANGES WITH 239:
          [...]

        * When loading unit files, systemd will now look for drop-in unit files
          extensions in additional places. Previously, for a unit file name
          "foo-bar-baz.service" it would look for dropin files in
          "foo-bar-baz.service.d/*.conf". Now, it will also look in
          "foo-bar-.service.d/*.conf" and "foo-.service.d/", i.e. at the
          service name truncated after all inner dashes. This scheme allows
          writing drop-ins easily that apply to a whole set of unit files at
          once. It's particularly useful for mount and slice units (as their
          naming is prefix based), but is also useful for service and other
          units, for packages that install multiple unit files at once,
          following a strict naming regime of beginning the unit file name with
          the package's name. Two new specifiers are now supported in unit
          files to match this: %j and %J are replaced by the part of the unit
          name following the last dash.

Either upgrade your system, or configure PAM to auto-generate individual drop-ins for each slice whenever a new UID logs in. You can use pam_exec.so for this – add it to the session section above pam_systemd (the latter is what registers the user slices), and make it call a script that creates drop-ins under /run/systemd.
#!/bin/bash
if [ "${PAM_TYPE?}" = open_session ]; then
    uid=$(id -u "${PAM_USER?}")
    cat > "/run/systemd/system/user-$uid.slice.d/limits.conf" <<-EOF
    ...
    EOF
fi


Same is working with Alma 8 / 9 .

Those have a newer systemd version.
